# Does this qualify as a proof of $\sum _{k=0}^{l}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k} = \binom{n+m}{l}$? (Spivak's 'Calculus')

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm working through Spivak's 'Calculus' at the moment, and a question about series confused me a bit. I think I have the solution, but I'm not sure if my "proof" holds.

The question is:

> Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{l}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k} = \binom{n+m}{l}$
>
> **Hint:** Apply the binomial theorem to $(1+x)^{n}(1+x)^{m}$

So I expanded $(1+x)^{n}(1+x)^{m}$, then expanded that again, and compared that to $(1+x)^{n+m}$, to get the equality:

$$\begin{align*}
&\binom{n}{0}\binom{m}{0} + \left [ \binom{n}{0}\binom{m}{1} + \binom{n}{1}\binom{m}{0} \right ]x \\
&+ \left [ \binom{n}{0}\binom{m}{2} + \binom{n}{1}\binom{m}{1} + \binom{n}{2}\binom{m}{0} \right ]x^{2} + \cdots\\
&\qquad = \binom{n+m}{0} + \binom{n+m}{1}x + \binom{n+m}{2}x^{2} + \cdots
\end{align*}$$

Now, my question is, is the original statement proven, just because the terms match up on both sides of the equality, or is this insufficient?

Thanks.

Comment: For completeness: what you have there is the well-known **Chu-Vandermonde identity**, about which much has been said. A strategy like yours is a common way to prove such convolution identities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two polynomials are equal iff they have equal degree and equal coefficients.

This statement directly follows from the following fact: if 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^m a_k x^k
$$
then
$$
a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}
$$

Comment: Not the most detailed, but it's really all I needed, thanks.

Comment: @SiliconCelery Do you know why this is true? If not, your proof might be circular. That's why Michael sketched a proof. See the links in my comment to Michael's answer.

Answer (score 4):

It works as a proof if you know that two polynomials are equal **only** if their coefficients match.

If they're equal, then one of them minus the other is zero, regardless of the value of $x$.  So now the problem is to show that a polynomial is zero for all $x$ **only** if its coefficients are zero.  If it has a nonzero coefficient, find the one of lowest degree.  If that's the zeroth-degree term, consider what happens when $x=0$.  Otherwise, you've got
$$
a_k x^k + \text{higher-degree terms} = x^k(a_k + \underbrace{a_{k+1}x + a_{k+2}x^2+\cdots+a_n x^n}).
$$
Since $a_k\ne 0$, it's enough to show that one can make $x\ne0$ so small by comparision to all of $|a_k|,|a_{k+1},\ldots,|a_n|$ that the expression over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ cannot cancel out $a_k$.

Comment: Or use the factor theorem and induction as in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/111309/242) See also the optimization in that thread using *continuity* of polynomials (hint: $\rm\:f(x)\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\: f(x)/x\equiv 0).$