# Spivak's Calculus - Exercise 4.a of 2nd chapter

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> 4 . (a) Prove that
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^l \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{l-k} = \binom{n+m}{l}.$$
>   Hint: Apply the binomial theorem to $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m$.

I'm having a hard time trying to solve the problem above. I've done all of the previous exercises of the 2nd chapter with little difficulty, so far. I think I might be missing a trivial point somewhere.

---

The answer I got from the Answer Book, and is not very helpful either... :(

> 4. (a) Since $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m = (1+x)^{n+m}$
>  we have
>  $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k\cdot\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j}x^j\cdot=\sum_{l=0}^{n+m} \binom{n+m}{l}x^l$$
>  But the coefficient of $x^l$ on the left is **clearly** $$\sum_{k=0}^l\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k}.$$
>  One term of the sum occurring for each pair $k$, $j = l-k$.

I couldn't get the last part of the answer:
why is it that the "coefficient of $x^l$ on the left is **clearly** $\sum_{k=0}^l\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k}$."?

Comment: You need to locate the coefficient of $x^l$ - and this is done by picking out the relevant terms on the left hand side with $l=0+l=1+(l-1)=2+(l-2)=\dots=(l-1)+1=l+0$ - the sum adds all these coefficients together.

Comment: I'm sorry, what you said wasn't very clear to me. Isn't the "coefficient of $x^l$" mentioned simply $\binom{n+m}{l}$?

Comment: See also:
[Does this qualify as a proof? (Spivak's 'Calculus')](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174810/does-this-qualify-as-a-proof-spivaks-calculus) and
[Combinatorial interpretation for the identity $\sum\limits_i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{j-i}=\binom{m+n}{j}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91457/combinatorial-interpretation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-i-binommi-binomn). (And maybe some questions linked to these questions.)

Comment: Indeed it is if you look at the right hand side of the expression. But if you look at the left hand side you find that this coefficient is split up into pieces - the sum of the pieces is equal to the coefficient - that is what the equation is saying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multiplication of formal power series is performed by collecting the terms with the same powers of $x$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=0}^k a_j\color{#C00000}{x^j}b_{k-j}\color{#C00000}{x^{k-j}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=0}^k a_jb_{k-j}\right)\color{#C00000}{x^k}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Note that the subscripts in the inner sum add up to $k$, the power of $x$ in the outer sum.

Apply $(1)$ to the product of
$$
(1+x)^m=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{m}{k}x^k\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}x^k\tag{3}
$$
which is
$$
(1+x)^{m+n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{m+n}{k}x^k\tag{4}
$$
I extended the indices in the sums to $\infty$ since for $k>n$, $\binom{n}{k}=0$.

For the product of $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get
$$
(1+x)^m(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{m}{j}\binom{n}{k-j}\right)x^k\tag{5}
$$
Comparing the coefficients of $x^k$ in $(4)$ and $(5)$ yields
$$
\binom{m+n}{k}=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{m}{j}\binom{n}{k-j}\tag{6}
$$
as desired.

Comment: that was most helpful, thank you!

Comment: For understanding the first part, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449388/understanding-power-series-multiplication-step) .

Comment: @YamMarcovic: that formula is known as the [Cauchy Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: @robjohn Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this will help you think about the coefficients. We have $n$ boys and $m$ girls, and we want to form a committee of $l$ people from these $n+m$ people. Clearly there are $\binom{n+m}{l}$ ways to form the committee.

Let's count the number of committees another way. We could have $0$ boys and $l$ girls. Such a committee can be formed in $\binom{n}{0}\binom{m}{l}$ ways.

Or we could have $1$ boy and $l-1$ girls. Such a committee can be formed in $\binom{n}{1}\binom{m}{l-1}$ ways.

Or we could have $2$ boys and $l-2$ girls. Such a committee can be formed in $\binom{n}{2}\binom{m}{l-2}$ ways.

Continue. The total number of committees is
$$\sum_{k=0}^l \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k}.\tag{$1$}$$
But we already saw that the number of committees is $\binom{n+m}{l}$.

**Note:** It is possible that for example there is a total of $3$ boys and $24$ girls, and we want to form a committee of $7$ people. Then the formula *appears* to break down. But it doesn't if we agree that $\binom{a}{b}=0$ if $b\gt a$.

To apply the reasoning to $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m$, you might first look at $(1+x)^n(1+y)^m$, and set $y=x$ at the end. So expand both, multiply. For fixed $l$, gather together terms that have a combined total of $l$ $x$'s (boys) and/or $y$'s. The total number will be given by Formula $(1)$.

Comment: that was very very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Note that since $\binom{n}{k} = {n (n-1)\cdots (n-k+1) \over k!}$, we can let $\binom{n}{k} = 0 $ if $k > n$. This will simplify notation.

Adopting this convention, we get
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}x^k\cdot\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{m}{j}x^j = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{j}x^{k+j}$.

Let $I_1 = \{ (k,j) | k, j \ge 0 \}$ and $I_2 = \{ (p,l) | 0 \le p \le l \}$, then we have
$I_1 = \{ (p, l-p) | (p,l) \in I_2 \}$.

Here is one way to see this: Define the linear operator $\phi((x,y) = (x,x+y)$, the inverse is $\phi^{-1} ((x,y)) = (x,y-x)$. It is straighforward to check that $\phi(I_1) \subset I_2$ and $\phi^{-1}(I_2) \subset I_1$, hence $\phi(I_1) = I_2$.

In particular, $f$ is zero for all but a finite number of terms, we have
$\sum_{(k,j) \in I_1} f(k,j) = \sum_{(p,l) \in I_2} f(p,l-p)$.

Hence we can write
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{(k,j) \in I_1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{j}x^{k+j} &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{j}x^{k+j} \\
&=& \sum_{(p,l) \in I_2} \binom{n}{p} \binom{m}{l-p}x^{l} \\
&=& \sum_{l=0}^{^\infty} \sum_{p=0}^l \binom{n}{p} \binom{m}{l-p}x^{l}
\end{eqnarray}
Now we have
$$\sum_{l=0}^{^\infty} \sum_{p=0}^l \binom{n}{p} \binom{m}{l-p}x^{l} = \sum_{l=0}^{^\infty} \binom{n+m}{l}x^l ,$$
which are polynomials of $x$ on both sides (note that only a finite number of coefficients can be non zero). Since this equality is true for all $x$, the polynomials are equal and hence so are the coefficients of each $x^l$ (differentiate $l$ times and set $x=0$ to convince yourself). It follows that
$$\sum_{p=0}^l \binom{n}{p} \binom{m}{l-p} = \binom{n+m}{l} .$$

Comment: Hi, I am trying to understand arriving at the right side of this: $$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{j}x^{k+j} = \sum_{l=0}^{n+m} \sum_{p=0}^l \binom{n}{p} \binom{m}{l-p}x^{l}.$$ Specifically the $l-p$ part.  Maybe a hint on the "convince yourself" part?

Comment: @lopan THere is something wrong there, thanks for catching that.

Comment: @lopan I added a fix.

Comment: Thanks.  I am struggling with the index set notation here: $(k,j) = p(1, -1) + l(0,1)$ which could apparently be written $(k,j) = k(1, -1) + k+j(0,1)$  Assume for instance $(k,j) = (1,1)$, how should I interpret the resulting notation $1(1,-1) + 2(0,1)$?  Just not clear on what this is expressing conceptually.

Comment: @lopan I added a few edits, hopefully this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I am getting there.  Since $k+j=l$, we have $j=l-k$.  We let $k=p$, $j=l-p$.  Since $k=p$ why is it the counter on the outer loop prior to our transformation, but it is the counter on the inner loop afterward?

Comment: @lopan I could easily have made a mistake, let me check.

Comment: @lopan Don't think of it like that. Think of it as summing over a set of indices (which is what it is). If you are comfortable with $\sum_{(k,j) \in I_1} f(k,j) = \sum_{(p,l) \in I_2} f(p,l-p)$, then we can write the right hand side as $\sum_{(p,l) \in I_2} f(p,l-p) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{p=0}^l f(p,l-p)$.

Comment: @lopan Another view point: If you are comfortable with $\phi(I_1) = I_2$ and the fact that $\phi$ is a bijection, then we have $\sum_{(k,j) \in I_1} f(k,j) = \sum_{(k,j) \in \phi^{-1}(I_2)} f(k,j) =\sum_{(p,l) \in I_2} f \circ \phi^{-1}(p,l-p) =\sum_{(p,l) \in I_2} f(p,l-p)$.

Comment: I finally see the big picture, but I'll have to plead insanity for the time being on the index set machinery.  Essentially, the left-side is generating a sum of all the terms systematically by iterating on $(k,j)$, but the point of the right-side is to generate the sums of like coefficients grouped by exponents of $x$ from $0$ to $n+m$ which prepares the proof that each such sum on the left corresponds to and equals $n+m \choose l$ where $l$ is the exponent of $x$.  I'm not sure now whether I feel like breakdancing or vomiting, but I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: "Like coefficients" meaning the $l+1$ ways to choose $l$ from $n+m$.

Comment: @lopan sometimes I stare at stuff again and again for hours before I get the point.

Answer (score 4):

If you multiply $c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_nx^n$ by $d_0+d_1x+\cdots+d_mx^m$, then for $k\leq\min(n,m)$ you will get terms involving $x^k$ from the products $c_0\times d_kx^k$, $\,c_1x\times d_{k-1}x^{k-1}$, $\,c_2x^2\times d_{k-2}x^{k-2}$,..., $c_kx^k\times d_0$, and from no other products. Adding those contributions gives $(c_0d_k+c_1d_{k-1}+c_2d_{k-2}+\cdots+c_kd_0)x^k$. Even if one should have $k>\min(n,m)$, the coefficient of $x^k$ is *clearly* always the sum of all $c_id_j$ with $i+j=k$, which you can write as $\sum_{i=0}^kc_id_{k-i}$ provided one defines $c_i$ or $d_j$ to be $0$ when the subscript is too large. And in your example the binomial coefficient expressions indeed become $0$ when the lower index is too large.

Answer (score 2):

You should determine the coefficient of $x^l$ in $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m$ in two ways. First multiply this out to get $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m=(1+x)^{n+m}$.  So considering the right hand side and using the binomial theorem we get $\binom{n+m}{l}$.

Now consider the coefficient of $x^l$ in the left hand side after expanding each term using the binomial theorem
$$(1+x)^n(1+x)^m=(\sum_{p=0}^m \binom{m}{p}x^p)(\sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}x^q)$$ You get a coefficient of $x^l$ in the product when you multiply $\binom{m}{p}x^p\binom{n}{q}x^q$ when $p+q=l$, i.e. $q=l-p$.

Then we have to take into account all the ways this can happen and comparing it to what we got on the right side so we have
$$\sum_{p=0}^l\binom{m}{p}\binom{n}{l-p}=\binom{m+n}{l}$$

Answer (score 0):

I thought proof by induction would be interesting which uses a property of Pascal's triangle. Assume it is true for $<l$. Induction on $n+m$. For $n=0$ it is true. Assume that it is true for $n$. For $n+1$,
$$\binom{n+1+m}{l}=\sum_{k=0}^l\binom{n+1}{k}\binom{m}{l-k}=\sum_{k=0}^l\left[\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}\right]\binom{m}{l-k}=\hspace{1cm}\binom{n+m}{l}+\sum_{k=1}^l\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{m}{l-k}$$
Hence we get
$$\binom{n+1+m}{l}-\binom{n+m}{l}=\sum_{k+1=1}^{k+1=l}\binom{n}{(k+1)-1}\binom{m}{l-(k+1)}$$
$$\binom{n+m}{l-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{(l-1)-k}$$
which is true by induction..

Comment: For what it's worth, the point of the exercise in the book was to deduce it directly by multiplying the two binomials, as the hint directed. You're in effect duplicating the effort of proving the binomial theorem, which was already done in the preceding problem.

Comment: I didn't know. I tried a different solution. If OP dislikes I delete.

Comment: Well, IMHO you should try to respond to the particular question the OP asked before giving a completely different argument.

Comment: You are right... I thought 10 years later he may be interested in different solutions... And there are enough answers, why is this question not closed?

Comment: Questions are not closed for being old. Note that the OP already accepted an answer which actually addressed his specific question.

Comment: Curioisty is more important than acceptance.