# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^\ell \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{\ell-k}=\binom{n+m}{\ell}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is problem 4a of Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th Edition, Prologue Chapter 2:

> Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^\ell \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{\ell-k}=\binom{n+m}{\ell}$$
> Hint: Apply the binomial theorem to $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m$.

And this is the solution

> Since $$(1+x)^n(1+x)^m=(1+x)^{n+m}$$ we have
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k\;\cdot\; \sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}x^j \;=\; \sum_{\ell=0}^{n+m} \binom{n+m}{\ell}x^\ell.$$
> But the coefficient of $x^\ell$ on the left is clearly
> $$\sum_{k=0}^\ell\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{\ell-k},$$
> one term of the sum occurring for each pair $k$, $j=\ell-k$.

It's frustrating when a solution uses terms like "clearly", and then you look at an equation and don't see it at all.

> How is the coefficient of $x^l$ "clearly" the expression shown in the solution above?

Comment: Have you tried considering an example? For instance, $m = 2$ and $n = 3$.

Comment: I agree that the use of "clearly" here is unwarranted and frustrating

Comment: This is [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), asked many times (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47868/vandermondes-identity-how-to-find-a-closed-formula-for-the-given-summation)).

Comment: It’s just the usual product of two polynomials. If you write them out instead of using a summation, it should be fairly clear. Or you could observe that the coefficient of $x^\ell$ on the left is the sum of all terms $\binom{n}k\binom{m}j$ such that $k+m=\ell$, and since that means that $m=\ell-k$, that gives you the desired result.

Comment: See explanation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3951400/754927

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lefthand side is of the form
$$(a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n)(b_0 + b_1 x + \dots + b_x x^m),$$
where $a_k = \binom{n}{k}$ and $b_j = \binom{m}{j}$. When we multiply everything out, when will terms of the form $c x^\ell$ appear?

Well, when a left term $a_k x^k$ meets a right term $b_j x^j$, we get a resulting term $a_k b_j x^{k + j}$. Thus, we are looking for pairs $(a_k x^k, b_j x^j)$ where $k + j = \ell$.

P.S. I agree with your sentiment that phrases like "clearly" are frustrating. You might like [this](http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/teaching-resources/documents/Su-Mathematical-Microaggressions.pdf) article by Francis Su on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{n+m}{l}$ counts the ways of choosing $l$ items from a collection of $n+m$ items. Think your collection as having $n$ blue items and $m$ red ones. In order to choose $l$ items from your collection, you can first choose some blue ones, say $k$ of them, and then you can choose the rest $l-k$ from the red ones.

Answer (score 1):

One formal derivation of the "clear" observation using a change in the index of summation $l = k + j$, or equivalently $j = l-k$.
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^k \cdot  \sum_{j=0}^m \binom mj x^j &= 
\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \binom mj x^{k + j}
\\ & = \sum_{l=0}^{m+n} \sum_{k=0}^l \binom nk \binom m{[l - k]}x^{k + [l-k]}
\\ & = \sum_{l=0}^{m+n} \sum_{k=0}^l \binom nk \binom m{l - k}x^{l}
 = \sum_{l=0}^{m+n} \left[\sum_{k=0}^l \binom m{l - k}\binom nk\right]x^{l}.
\end{align}

Comment: Are there errors in the summation indices above? For example, doesn't j go from 0 to m? Once you change the index to l = k + j, doesn't l go from i to m+n?

Comment: @evianpring I indeed made mistakes with the indices. See my latest edit. Note that the double summation is meant to denote a nested sum, so it doesn't make sense for the limits of $l$ to depend on the "internal" index $k$.

Comment: Ok, I need to learn a bit more about when and how to change summation indices.