# Looking for proof of $\sum_1^n \alpha_i x^i = 0 \;\; \Longrightarrow \;\; \alpha_i = 0, \forall\;i$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The assertion in the subject line is an abbreviated form of:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x^i = 0, \forall \; x \in {\mathbb R} \;\; \Longrightarrow \;\; \alpha_i = 0, \forall\;i \in \{1, \dots , n\}.$$

In words: if for all real $x$, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x^i$ is always $0$, then all the coefficients $\alpha_i$ must be $0$.

I can't readily come up with a formal proof of this, though it seems to me "obviously" true: it's an uncountable number of equations against a finite number of unknowns.

> A *pointer* to a nice, illuminating proof would be appreciated.

I often come across unproven assertions that I accept on the basis of exactly that same informal argument ("more equations than degrees of freedom"), but I'd like to be able to think about this stuff a bit more rigorously.  So what I'm *really* after is an approach/technique for proving assertions about "overdetermined" systems of this kind.<sup>1</sup>

Needless to say, an "elementary" proof, based only on basic algebra, is far preferable to one relying on some other non-obvious result.

Also, since the informal argument given above does not depend on all the properties of ${\mathbb R}$, one expects that the assertion would remain true if we replace ${\mathbb R}$ with a more general (though still infinite) structure.  An *elementary* proof of the theorem in its full generality would be really nice too.  I realize that such a proof may run over many pages, hence I don't ask for a proof necessarily, but rather for a pointer to one.

BTW, I didn't know how to Google for this proof because I could not come up with adequate search terms.  Does this theorem have a standard name?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>An example of what I mean here would be the common trick of using the sequence $\{2^{-i}\}_{i=1}^\infty$, to construct proofs requiring a non-infinite sum of infinitely many terms.  Or Cantor's diagonalization trick.  Once one learns them, tricks like these become second-nature, and turn some previously challenging proofs into routine ones.  I'm hoping to find the trick that makes proving the assertion in the subject line routine.</sub>

Comment: Differentiate, take $x=0$. Continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ f(\Bbb R)=0\:\Rightarrow\:f(\Bbb N) = 0.\:$ Suppose that there exists a nonzero polynomial with $\rm\,f(\Bbb N) = 0.\:$ Choose one of minimal degree. Then $\rm\:f(0)=0\:$ so $\rm\:f(x) = x\,g(x).\:$ For $\rm\,n\ge 1\!:\,$  $\rm\,f(n) = n g(n) = 0\:$ so $\rm\:g(n) = 0.\:$  Hence $\rm\:g(x\!+\!1)\:$ is zero on $\,\Bbb N,\:$ and $\rm\,deg\ g < deg\ f,\,$ contra minimality of $\rm\,f(x).$

**Remark** $\ $ Alternatively, one can work over $\rm\,\Bbb R\,$ and use the *continuity* of polynomials to deduce that the polynomial $\rm\,g(x) = f(x)/x\,$ has $\rm\:g(0) = 0,\,$ e.g. see this thread: [Apostol proof divides by zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108308/23500) See my remarks there for how this is related to the factor theorem.

Generally a polynomial $\ne 0$ with coefficients in a *field* has no more roots than its degree. For more general rings this fails. It is true iff the coefficient ring is a domain, i.e. $\rm\:cd = 0\:\Rightarrow\:c=0\ or\ d=0.\:$ Note that the above proof used this property: $\rm\: n\ne 0,\ n\,g(n)=0\:\Rightarrow\:g(n)=0.\:$ For non-domain failures note $\rm\:2x = 0\:$ has $2$ roots $\rm\:x = 2,0\:$ mod $4$, and $\rm\:x^2 = 1\:$ has $4$ roots $\rm\:x = \pm1,\pm3\:$ mod $8$.

Comment: @Math Gems Why didn't you stay in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @GitGud Because the essence of the matter, that a polynomial has no more roots than its degree, has nothing to do with $\,\Bbb R\:$ (or continuity). Rather, it depends only on the ability to cancel nonzero coefficients, i.e. that the coefficient ring is a domain (e.g. a field).

Comment: @MathGems Yes, so why didn't you stay in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Git Gud The proof nolonger works with $\mathbb{R}$ since we lose $g(0)=0$. It works for $\mathbb{R}^*$.

Comment: @julien The same way Math Gems took $n\ge 1$, he can take $x\ge 1$ and everything works just the same.

Comment: @GitGud The first proof works over $\,\Bbb R\,$ too! The only advantage of using continuity in the linked Apostol proof is that it eliminates the need to shift $\rm\,x \to x\!+\!1\:$ to get the roots of $\rm\:g(x)\:$ from all $\rm\:n\ge 1\:$ to all $\rm\:n\ge 0.\ \ $

Comment: @Git Gud Yes, that's why I mentioned $\mathbb{R}^*$. But indeed $[1,+\infty)$ works equally well. So $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{R}^*$, $[1,+\infty)$... I don't see more here than a matter of taste. As for taste, I believe the most elementary proof of this result is by differentiating and evaluating at $0$ repeatedly.

Comment: @Julien Yes, that's another standard proof (which requires knowledge of calculus - which the algebraic proofs do not).

Comment: @MathGems Your proof does not, which is why I like it actually better than mine. But for those who use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, there is quite a bit of calculus hidden under the rug...

Comment: @MathGems: I really like your proof, but I don't share your typesetting tastes...  I find text like "Then $\rm\:f(0)=0\:$ so $\rm\:f(x) = x\,g(x).\:$ For $\rm\,n\ge 1\!:\,$  $\rm\,f(n) = n g(n) = 0\:$ so $\rm\:g(n) = 0.\:$" noticeably harder to read than "Then $f(0)=0$ so $f(x) = x\,g(x).$  For $n \ge 1\!:\,f(n) = n\,g(n) = 0$ so $g(n) = 0.$"

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint}:$ Consider the polynomial $P(t)=\alpha _n t^n + \cdots + \alpha _1t$.

Your hypothesis says that every real number $x$ is a root of this polynomial.

Proceed.

Answer (score 2):

In any field $K$, a non-zero polynomial $p(x) \in K[x]$ of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ roots. Your polynomial has infinite roots. So, it must be the zero polynomial.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for just a tip.

Comment: @GitGud: sorry that I was not sufficiently clear: what I meant was that, in case that an elementary proof would be too long to write out (which I thought likely), a pointer to such a proof would suffice.

Comment: @kjo No problem. The important thing is that you're happy with the answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $x_1,..,x_n$ are pairwise distinct the following determinant is non-zero:

$$\det\pmatrix{1 &x_1 &x_1^2 &..&x_1^{n-1}\\1 &x_2 &x_2^2 &..&x_2^{n-1}\\... &... &.. &..&.\\1 &x_n &x_n^2 &..&x_n^{n-1}}\neq 0$$

If you don't see why this happen, I can post the closed formula for that determinant.

Comment: Hooray! Vandermonde! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: @julien Yup. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the $a_k$'s are not all equal to $0$.
Let $m$ be the smallest integer such that $a_m\neq 0$.

Dividing the initial equation by $x^m$ when $x\neq 0$, we get
$$
a_m+a_{m+1}x+\ldots+a_{n}x^{n-m}=0\qquad\forall x\neq 0.
$$

Now letting $x\rightarrow 0$, we find $a_m=0$, a contradiction.

So the $a_k$'s are all $0$.

Comment: That's the proof by continuity in Apostol's textbook (that I linked to in my answer)

Comment: @Math Gems Are you telling me I should delete this answer, then?

Comment: No, I hoped my comment would encourage readers to follow my link to the [prior thread on Apostol's proof,](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/108308/23500) since the answers there discuss at length the subtleties of this method of proof, such as whether or not it does divide by zero.